# Create subdomains via C-Panel or via domain registrar?

Tags: dns, subdomain, domain-registration, cpanel

I am a novice, so excuse me if it sounds dummy. I read a few similar questions on this topic here but they did not answer my question.

I have a personal website, hosted with C-panel control panel. Via C-panel I can easily create new subdomains and I do not need to apply any DNS settings or so. And the subdomian is good to go immediately and are working fine. I have unlimited subdomains option.

When I check my DNS management control panel in my domain registrar's site, there is no record associated with my subdomains.

Now I want to buy a new domain name from 1and1, and have it as an add-on domain in my prevouse host. 1and1 say they only allow 5 subdomains. What does this mean? Can not I create unlimited subdomains under my new domain name, just as I do for my old domain?

How does C-panel create and manage subdomains that there is nothing about it in my DNS control panel?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

> I have unlimited subdomains option.
>
> When I check my DNS management control panel in my domain registrar's site
>
> Now I want to buy a new domain name from 1and1, and have it as an add-on domain in my prevouse host.

It sounds like your hosting isn't with 1&1, only your domain registration. Therefore 1&1's sub-domain limitations do not apply.

Add-on and sub-domains you create in cPanel do not need DNS entries as they will share the same IP address. They are created as VirtualHosts in apache config.

As long as your main domain (eg, example.com) A record is pointed to your hosting IP address, then you can create as many sub-domains as you like.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of getting subdomains. One is that the DNS is set up so that every subdomain gets sent to your server (wildcard DNS record) and then the server is configured to display different sites at each subdomain.

The other is that the subdomains are set up on the DNS explicitly and are associated with an IP address of a server that is configured to display the appropriate site at those subdomains.

It sounds like 1and1 are doing the second thing.

The way add-on domains work is that if your main hosting is at example.com and you add-on example2.com then behind the scenes a new subdomain is created example2.example.com and example2.com is redirected to that. From the research I've done it doesn't appear that you can have sub-sub-domains, so you can't have sub.example2.com because you can't have sub.sub.example.com, which is what it would need to map to behind the scenes.

Comment: For Cnames they are created where your DNS is hosted.  Most registrars offer DNS hosting, or you can use Amazon Route or other DNS providers which have more features.

Comment: To use Amazon Route 53, or your hosting company for DNS management. You will need to setup custom name servers at the registrar level. Only then can you start using your hosting providers DNS features.

Comment: @paulmorriss , thanks for the reply. But I think you can have practically a large number of domain levels. sub.sub.sub.sub.mysite.com is possible and I already have that.

Comment: @Anagio, apparently 1and1 does not allow using other DNS servers other thatn their (1and1's DNS server).

So with these conditions, Can I use an A-record rule to catch all wildcard sub-domains and redirect them to my main domain, hoping that my infinite number of subdomains that I create and manage with CPnale (my hosting control panel) will direct each subdomain to the correct folder in my hosting?

Comment: That is to say, if I set the following A record, in my DNS control panel of domain registrar, 
*.example.com.  A [my site's IP]
and I create sub1.example.com and sub2.example.com with CPanel in my hosting control planel, someone typying sub1.example.com in their browsers will end up in the right place (the corresponding pages on that subdomain)? or he/she will just see the main page of example.com ?

Comment: Yes, if example.com is your main domain. The problem is with subdomains on an additional domain name.

Comment: @paulmorriss, just an update. I had my second domain as an add-on to my main website. now both domains are working fine with same hosting plan. and yes, I can have subdomains for each domains separately. I tried till 3-level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer now that i've done some more research regarding your subdomains. 1&1 apparently does not allow unlimited subdomains. See their FAQ here http://faq.1and1.com/domains/domains_explained/subdomains/5.html

Each pricing plan comes with a set quantity of subdomains allowed per main domain.

Creating an A record wildcard subdomain might be a work around but you will need to setup rules in either .htaccess or your application to monitor the URL and that's not guaranteed to work and will take up time to write the code.

My suggestion is to switch hosts to http://www.hostmonster.com/cgi/info/hosting_features they offer unlimited domains, and unlimited sub-domains. So you can have all your domains in one account and easily, very easily manage your sub-domains. They also use cPanel so you'll be comfortable with them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access and WHM management for your cPanel server, you can create and use your own private nameservers and bypass any limits 1and1 has on your DNS records.  So after your nameservers are registered and set up (another topic I can help with), change the domain's nameservers at 1and1 and you can do all the DNS management in WHM/cPanel.

You will need an extra IP on the server so each nameserver is on a different IP (the 1st nameserver can use the main shared IP).

Comment: The problem with 1and1 was that normaly they do not allow using any other DNS server except theirs. Or you can pay much higher price to have that option activated for you probably!

I read so man bad things about them on the net that I decided to buy from another registrar.